# Button to Select Random Cell in tableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, button

How could I create a button on the Table View that when touched randomly selects one of the cells?

I know how to add Round Rect Button and all, just not the code part of selecting a random cell.

Thanks!

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
        //   destViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
```

[image: Code]

[image]

Comment: how many sections do you have in your tableView? I mean to say only one section or multiple sections.

Answer (score 1):

Hello as you have mentioned in your comment that you have only one section with 36 cells. find the rendom row using `arc4random`.

Then fetch your `indexPath` from section and row.

then call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Whole code of your button click method will look like....

```
int section = 0;
int row = arc4random() %35;
NSIndexPath * path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
if ([self.yourTableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [self.yourTableView.delegate tableView:self.yourTableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
}

[self.yourTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];    

if ([self.yourTableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [self.yourTableView.delegate tableView:self.yourTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
}
```

Then implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     btn.tag = indexPath.row;
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showRecipeDetail" sender:btn];
}
```

Make sure that you have written following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.yourTableView.delegate = self;
self.yourTableView.dataSource = self;
```

And change `prepareForSegue` method as below

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {

        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

        destViewController.recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:tagIndex];
    }
}
```

This will surely help you.....

Comment: sorry for the crash. Please see the EDIT i have made to answer. And if still it crashes, please mention crash error.

Comment: Crashed again... Crash code in my EDIT above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: make sure that you have assigned delegates to your tableView

Comment: Okay now it works! However, it doesn't open to the detailViewcontroller, it only highlights the cell eachtime. Any guidance on fixing that? You're awesome!

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. Have you implemented `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` OR `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in your code.if not then implement one of them. if yes then show me the coding for that.

Comment: the code is fine. but i am talking about implementation of `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` OR `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. See my edit.

Comment: Hmmm, made the edits, but it still highlights each cell. Do I need any code in the detailViewController?

Comment: please show the code of your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: Besides the one you gave me earlier, I do not have any code for that. All I have for that is updated above.

Comment: OK Let me explain! What you want to perform after selection of the random cell.

Comment: Oh no sorry, not sure what you mean't in the other comment?

Comment: I mean to say give me the code you want to perform after selection of cell. like if you want to open the other view controller or any thing else!

Comment: Yes, I want to open the other view controller which is the detailViewcontroller for each cell. I updated what I have above.

Comment: where have you written that code? Show me !!!! May be this is the last step of your solution.

Comment: It is the last code on the viewController that contains the information of each cell. There's an additional viewController called the detailViewController that is the actual linking for each cell page. Screenshot Above

Comment: Make change to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue` methods as my edit to this question.

Comment: Please check the spellings if i have spell wrong any word. But Logic is perfect .

Comment: The button works perfect, but when I do not use the button and touch on an individual cell, I get this error 2013-07-09 11:57:00.124 Menu[61418:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <RecipeDetailViewController: 0x9ce5e20>.